# Junit (DisplayName аннотация) и создание экземпляра в методе с аннотацией BeforeEach

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Вопрос  закрыт,  спасибо всем.

Comment: А где сам класс?

Comment: @RomanC добавил, извиняюсь.

Comment: @MikeMclaren, ну и в чём собственно _теперь_ заключается ваш вопрос?  Похоже, вам стоит удалить его полностью.

Answer (score 1):

В SetUp Вы создаете объект calculator, чтобы обратится к методу multiply() ниже в тесте. Если метод multiply() не статический то нет никакого другого способа обратится к нему, как только через экземпляр его класса...

@DislpayName не пишет ничего в консоль, слева на скрине Вы видите название тестов, если хотите что то писать в консоль, придется самостоятельно это делать через System.out.println() в самом простом варианта, или через Logger, если его все таки подключили.

Comment: Спасибо, тупанул что sout не написал, совсем заработался